# I am about to stain a new Redwood deck. Does anybody have first hand experience with a good stain for Direct/Heavy Sunlight?

Tags: staining

I am about to stain a new redwood deck. Does anybody have first-hand experience with a good stain for Direct/Heavy Sunlight? I live in a hot and arid part of Colorado and we have used a few different stains on some older wood fences and decks. They all failed.

This year we built a new deck and I am about to stain. I have read the reviews on a lot of expensive and inexpensive stains. I can't tell based on the even amounts of good vs. bad stains which one will hold up. I have read that oil-based is the way to go as opposed to water-based. We have a dog that frequents the deck and don't  want to see the trail from the dog walking up and down the deck.

Another question, I was reading here that you may want your deck to sit for an extended period of time before staining it. Is this recommended?

http://www.deckstainhelp.com/how-to-season-a-new-deck/

Comment: We have a couple related a possible duplicates: [one](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/3950/should-i-use-solid-color-wood-stain-or-paint-for-my-project), [two](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/3704/shellac-over-paint-outdoors), [three](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/2064/interior-or-exterior-stain-for-garage-steps-and-shelves), [four](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/1520/choosing-wood-and-finish-for-outdoor-furniture).  I'm sure there are others.

Comment: Also, no exterior wood stain is a permanent solution.  They ALL require some maintenance and reapplication from time to time.

Comment: I know there is some maintenance. I just want to make sure I don't have huge blotches and have to powerwash / destroy the deck a season after I stain because I picked a bad stain.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. I'm looking for specific feedback from anybody that has used a specific type of stain in desert-like conditions.

Comment: A more exact location in Colorado might help since the state is so diverse in climate.

Comment: Any part of Colorado, Arizona, Utah that is hot and sunny like a desert would fit the bill

Comment: This sounds like a home improvement question that might get more responses  at http://diy.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I definitely would wait to stain...two-three weeks should be enough. The wood has natural oils in it so waiting gives it time to dry out. Personally, I would use a natural color of stain that's for direct Sun. Wish I could suggest a certain brand. I'm thinking if done carefully and done right you would probably be safe using any of the main brands. Good luck!

Comment: I've done a bunch of research. Your comment makes a lot of sense. A lot of the stain companies suggest that you do this and from what I was reading a lot of people who pass on that info have issues with the stain after it applied.

Comment: I also read a lot about how stores like Home Depot and Lowes make companies decrease the quality of their products in order to make those products more marketable price wise in the stores so quality will greatly vary between say Home Depot and a specialty store selling the same product or the product will decrese in quality across the board. So when reading reviews on line one person pointed out that you need to know when the review was written, beofr eor after they started selling at the big brand stores. Doesn't make it easy to find a quality product. I am going with TWP

Comment: Seemed like a good reliable source: http://www.painttalk.com/f2/twp-1500-a-24611/

Comment: OH WOW! John Dangerous...I've never heard that stores encourage vendors to decrease quality of their product! That seems to me, it should be against some kind of law! That's crazy! Thanks for sharing that info!

Comment: Well I should clarify. They have companies bring down the cost of their product to be more competitive so as a result companies need to change their formula so they can afford to cut the prices on their products. A gallon of quality stain at a specialty store can be $60 - $70 but at home depot most stains are around $40 Dimensions for example use to cost more and now sells for $45. On the can it says something like new low price same recipe but from what I was reading online that is unlikely